# Xamarin iconize font class not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget, icons

I am implementing the Iconize nuget package for my new project. I want to use this package for displaying icons in my tabbedpage. While following the github repository instructions from Iconize I encountered the following problem:
Visual studio code doesn't seem to find the Fonts class. Did I configure something wrong? Or is it a problem in the overall nuget package? I pasted my app.cs class below.

[image: My current app.cs]

Comment: Any update about it?

Comment: If you have any other concern, please feel free to let us know:) We are willing to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

**The issue** is that the code you used are from different standalone nuget packages, not just a simple `Xam.Plugin.Iconize` nuget package.

**So** you should right-click on your **App1** project **Properties**-->**Manage Nuget Packages** and then make sure that you have installed these nuget packages:

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.EntypoPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.EntypoPlus/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Ionicons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Ionicons/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.JamIcons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.JamIcons/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Material](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Material/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Meteocons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Meteocons/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.SimpleLineIcons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.SimpleLineIcons/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Typicons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.Typicons/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

[Xam.Plugin.Iconize.WeatherIcons](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Iconize.WeatherIcons/3.5.0.129?_src=template)

You should install them all and then you can get the result well:

[image]

**Besides**, if you still get the error, you could try the following steps:

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, any `bin` and `obj` output folders. After that, restart your project to test again.

[image]